# Add space from the top for navigation title

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uistoryboard

Want to give additional space from the top for navigation title shopping list.  How can I do it?  Dont see a option to do it in the properties of navigation item in the story board.  Its close to the date, battery icon in the top of the app.

Attached the screenshot.

[image]

Tried the below code its not working using swift2

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
               navigationController?.navigationBar.setTitleVerticalPositionAdjustment(15,forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default) // set any number you want between -20 to 15


    }
```

Comment: so you want to move title vertical positioning further down ?.can you post simulator screenshot of your problem

Comment: yes vertical positioning further down.  Run directly on the iphone not on the simulator cant take a screenshot.

Comment: let me know.code works for you?

Comment: If you still having issue..let me know?

Answer (score 2):

Try this code: Tested in Swift 3.

**Note:** Method 1 works only, If your VC embedded with navigationController.In your case you only using navigationBar to show title.So, use method 2.

Method 1:

```
 navigationController?.navigationBar.setTitleVerticalPositionAdjustment(5, for: UIBarMetrics.default) // set any number you want between -20 to 15
```

Method 2:

```
 navigationBar.setTitleVerticalPositionAdjustment(10, for: UIBarMetrics.default) // navigationBar is the name of your navBar..
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Using swift2 Tried different values from -20 to 15 title position not moving.  Copied the code in viewdidload method. Pasted the code in edit section

Comment: sorry for the delay will try out and let you know