# iOS. UINavigationBar with custom height -> vertically center titleView & barButtonItems

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uikit

I have a custom `UINavigationBar`:

```
class NavBar: UINavigationBar {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.commonInit()
    }

    private func commonInit() {
        self.barTintColor = .orange

    }

    override func sizeThatFits(_ size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 66)
    }

}
```

When I set `titleView` and/or `barButtonItems` they are not vertically centered:

```
class ViewController : UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.viewDidLoad()

        self.edgesForExtendedLayout = []

        let searchField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 44))
        searchField.backgroundColor = .green
        self.navigationItem.titleView = searchField

    }


}
```

Result:

[image]

How can I vertically center `textView` & `barButtonItems` inside `UINavigationBar` when it's height is not default?

I've tried setting `textView`'s `bounds`, `frame` - does not work.

With:

```
        let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 44))
        view.backgroundColor = .green
        let searchField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: -20, width: 100, height: 44))
        searchField.backgroundColor = .red
        view.addSubview(searchField)
        self.navigationItem.titleView = view
```

I can change the position of the `searchField`, but it seems like I am doing it wrong.

Can I somehow set `UINavigationBar` 'padding'/'margin' or `textView` & `barButtonItem` `offset` in the `NavBar` class?

Comment: Check this post may helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40316352/increase-navigationbar-height/40320225#40320225 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40437255/add-space-from-the-top-for-navigation-title/40438244#40438244

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're basically hacking UINavigationBar right now that's why I wouldn't expect stable behaviour from it. Apple is discouraging your from doing that. Even in the [Apple example of extended UINavBar](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/NavBar/Introduction/Intro.html) they just adding another view and make transition between bar and view seamless. You can also try

```
setTitleVerticalPositionAdjustment(_:for:)
```

method but I believe it only affects title and not tab bar items. I would use apple solution to avoid unexpected issues or create custom nav bar without subclassing UINavBar.

Comment: This is what I am trying to achieve:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKaDh.png so you think it is better to use `UIView` instead of 'hacking' on the `UINavigationBar`?

Comment: Yes, you aren't leveraging `UINavigationBar`'s possibilities and you have much more control over what's going on in your custom view so I'd go with `UIView` but it's totally up to you.